# How do I logon to an exchange calendar from excel

Tags: vba, excel, outlook, calendar

I'm writing an excel macro that connects to a number of outlook(exchange) calendars using user credentials, and parses through the calendar data to output it to a spreadsheet. I've been able to grab calendar data from my local outlook application, but can't figure out how to log in to another account. Is this possible? There must be some way to access exchange calendars. From what I've gatherer already around the internet, I may be able to use MAPI? I just don't know how for this case.

```
Sub ListAppointments()
'Dim mapi_session As MSMAPI.MAPISession
'Set mapi_session = CreateObject("MSMAPI.MAPISession")
Dim olApp As Object
Dim olNS As Object
Dim olFolder As Object
Dim olApt As Object
Dim myStart As Date
Dim myEnd As Date
Dim NextRow As Long
Dim today, date1, date2
today = VBA.Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")

myStart = VBA.Format(Year(today) & "-" & Month(today) & "-01", "yyyy-mm-dd")
myEnd = DateAdd("m", 3, myStart)
date1 = InputBox("Enter range beginning date", , myStart)
date2 = InputBox("Enter range end date", , myEnd)
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
olNS.Logon "", "", False, True
Set olFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(9) 'olFolderCalendar

Range("A1:D1").Value = Array("Subject", "Start", "End", "Location")

NextRow = 2
For Each olApt In olFolder.Items
    If olApt.Start >= myStart And olApt.End <= myEnd Then
        Cells(NextRow, "A").Value = olApt.Subject
        Cells(NextRow, "B").Value = olApt.Start
        Cells(NextRow, "C").Value = olApt.End
        Cells(NextRow, "D").Value = olApt.Location
        NextRow = NextRow + 1
    End If
Next olApt

Set olApt = Nothing
Set olFolder = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

This is all I've got so far which just lets me grab local outlook data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `olNS.CreateRecipient` / `olNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(..., olFolderCalendar)` to open the Calendar folder of another Exchange mailbox.